# Using a complex object as a directive binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-typeahead

I have a field which is populated by a typeahead field. The typeahead field sets a complex object onto the model.

I want to use one of the properties on the typeahead result to populate my custom directive.

eg:

```
<something content='typeaheadResult.id'></something>
```

However it doesnt seem to update when the result is populated. I think this may be because typeaheadResult doesnt have an id property until the value is selected.

**How can i bind using a subpropery of the result?**

I have tried a few things such as using a computed value as an intermediate but nothing seems to work.

eg:

```
scope.resultId = function(){ 
    return typeaheadResult !== undefined ? typeaheadResult.id : ''; 
}
```

the directive works fine with non-typeahead scope values.

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/IKIMkeTQnbUJG3aUnT1s

Comment: Your problem here is that you have a condition inside the link function which invokes in an early state.
Later, your property changes and nothing happens. 
You need to add a watch or something on your property(in the link function, so it will listen to changes, and act on change). This can be done using jquery events e.g. on change or BETTER by using a watch on the property and add some conditions.
I can't give you a full answer with a code example since I'm in a rush, but I guess you can try doing this.

Comment: Something like this should work(didn't check this):
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch("content",function(o,n){
      if (o != null && n != null && o != n && n.id != null) {
    element.html(n.id);
   }
   });